# does function converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Does the sequence $(f_n)$ of functions  $f_n:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in (0,\frac1{n+1}) \\
       \sin^2 \frac\pi x& x \in [\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]\\
       0 & x \in (\frac1n, \infty)\end{cases}$$

converge uniformly?
I am fairly new to this and have no idea how to go about this so any help would be great.

Comment: Please format your question with LaTeX or mathjax to improve readability of this question. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
The pointwise limit of $f_n$ (note that $n$ is a parameter) is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 0 \qquad \forall\ x\in (0,\infty)$$
So the uniform limit is $0$ if it exists. Now see that
$$\sup_{\theta\in [n\pi, (n+1)\pi]} |\sin\theta| = 1$$
what do you conclude for $\|f_n - 0\|_\infty$? What does this mean for
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n\|_\infty$$

Comment: limit f(x) is not continouous so it cant converge uniformly would that be correct?

Comment: @stensoj3 $f_n$ _is_ continuous for every $n$ and $0$ is as continuous as a function can be.